# O que significa o operador && em entre strings?

Tags: javascript

Encontrei em um arquivo minificado do bootstrap, o seguinte:

```
e=e&&e.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/,"")
```

O operador `&&` parece estar sendo aplicado entre duas strings.

O que significa isso?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Significado do operador && no Javascript

O operador `&&` do javascript não é um simples operador lógico, como se costuma
deduzir observando-se o uso do mesmo operador em outras linguagens.

No javascript, isso:

```
valor1 && valor2
```

quer dizer exatamente o seguinte:

```
(valor1 ? valor2 : valor1)
```

Acontece, que no exemplo acima, o operador que vem antes do `?` é tratado pelo
javascript de forma lógica, ou seja, ele tenta converter `valor1` para
verdadeiro ou falso.

Se for verdadeiro, então o segundo operando é avaliado e retornado, se for falso, então o terceiro operando é avaliado e retornado. O operando oposto, ao que é avaliado, não será avaliado, ou seja, se o segundo e terceiro métodos fossem métodos, somente um deles seria chamado:

```
logico ? alert("TRUE") : alert("FALSE");
```

Somente um dos alert será chamado.

### Analise da expressão da pergunta

Então vamos ver o que acontece, quando substituimos a expressão original da
pergunta, usando a sintaxe alternativa do operador ternário:

```
e = e ? e.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, "") : e
```

Se `e` for avaliado de forma lógica como verdadeiro, então o resultado é o
replace, caso contrário é o próprio `e`. No caso, como se espera que `e` seja
uma string, podemos dizer a única forma de se avaliar `e` como verdadeiro,
é quando o mesmo não é nulo, undefined, nem uma string vazia.

O replace serve, provavelmente, para extrair o hash de uma URL:

- substituir qualquer coisa que seja seguida de: **'#'** + **string sem espaços**
- por string vazia

Exemplo: "http://www.xpto.com/abc?123#hash" vai tornar "#hash"

Então, o que o programador original provavelmente quis dizer é:

- se `e` for uma string com conteúdo, pegue o hash-tag dela,
  caso contrário deixe `e` do jeito que está: vazio, nulo ou undefined.

### Referência

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators