# Condição ternária JavaScript com somente um valor

Tags: javascript, if

Um dúvida bem básica de Javascript, em uma condição ternária como posso fazer para ter ação somente em um if sem a necessidade do else?

Exemplo

```
(test) ? test1() : test2();
```

Se não quiser que aconteça nada no Else, como ficaria?

Tentei, fazer como no PHP mais não deu certo:

```
(!test) ?: test1();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isso é possível com o operador `&&` da seguinte forma:

```
(test) && test1();
```

Nessa outra resposta, [O que significa o operador && em entre strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5864/o-que-significa-o-operador-em-entre-strings/5865#5865), eu mostro como exatamente funciona o operador `&&` no JavaScript, e porque é possível usar ele dessa forma... na verdade é uma equivalência direta: **`a && b` => `a ? b : a`**.

Quando se usa isso na forma de statement, o valor resultante é descartado, o que acaba fazendo com que pareça um `if` sem `else`.