# Qual a diferença entre o uso de arquivos .js e .min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando devo usar um arquivo JavaScript ou jQuery, com arquivo `min` e `js`puro, tipo:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Algumas das respostas responde sua questão @pnet? Caso positivo não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tomou-se como convenção, nomear arquivos javascript minificados, com a terminação `.min.js`.

### Diferenças

A diferença entre o arquivo minificado e o não minificado é o tamanho do arquivo... a **funcionalidade não muda** (ou pelo menos não deveria mudar, se isso ocorrer é um bug).

Os arquivos `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` e `jquery-1.10.2.js` devem possuir a mesma funcionalidade.

O arquivo não minificado **`.js`** é usado para **desenvolvimento e para debug**, pois ele é **legível para seres humanos**.

O arquivo minificado **`.min.js`** é usado **para produção**, pois é menor que aquele usado para desenvolvimento, e portanto vai **economizar na quantidade de banda** utilizada pelo servidor.

### Como funciona

A minificação consta de uma série de transformações no arquivo javascript original:

- **redução do tamanho dos nomes de variáveis**
- **remoção de comentários e espaços desnecessários**
- **remoção de caracteres não significativos** (e.g. alguns `;` ao final de statements são opcionais)
- **substituição de instruções equivalentes**, um exemplo que eu acho interessante, está nesta questão que eu levantei sobre o operador `&&` como substituto de um operador ternário, ou então como substituto de um `if` inteiro, dependendo do caso: [O que significa o operador && em entre strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5864/o-que-significa-o-operador-em-entre-strings/5865#5865); o operador `||` também pode ser usado em redução de tamanho de operações, como explico em uma outra resposta: [Existe no javascript um operador de coalescência nula? Tal como o operador ?? do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5052/existe-no-javascript-um-operador-de-coalescencia-nula-tal-como-o-operador-do/5053#5053)
- **cópia do corpo de funções** para o local da chamada, quando isso valer a pena (e.g. quando uma função é chamada apenas em um lugar do código)

### Ferramentas

Se algum dia você precisar minificar os seus próprios arquivos javascript, pode usar uma dessas ferramentas:

- [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)
- [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/)

**Referências**

- [Minification (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)
- [How does minification work and does it affect angular nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281171/how-does-minification-work-and-does-it-affect-angular-nested-objects)
- [Is there a good JavaScript minifier? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier) - ferramentas de minificação
- [Better JavaScript Minification](http://alistapart.com/article/better-javascript-minification) - sobre elementos do código javascript que dificultam a minificação
- [closure-compiler / src / com / google / javascript / jscomp /](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp) - código do `closure-compiler` que faz as referidas transformações de código javascript
- [closure-compiler / src / com / google / javascript / jscomp / InlineFunctions.java](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/InlineFunctions.java) - código de como é feito inlining de funções. Veja os comentários relevantes:

> These functions must meet these general requirements:
>
> - it is not recursive
> - the function does not contain another function -- these may be
>     intentional to to limit the scope of closures.
> - function is called only once OR the size of the inline function is smaller
>     than the call itself.
> - the function name is not referenced in any other manner

- outras otimizações:

  - as otimizações feitas substituindo-se blocos de `if` eu mesmo expliquei como funciona

    [O que significa o operador && em entre strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5864/o-que-significa-o-operador-em-entre-strings/5865#5865)

    [Existe no javascript um operador de coalescência nula? Tal como o operador ?? do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5052/existe-no-javascript-um-operador-de-coalescencia-nula-tal-como-o-operador-do/5053#5053)
  - as otimizações sobre nomes de variáveis e comentários: essa otimização é senso comum

Answer (score 8):

Arquivos `.min` vêm do inglês `minified`, que, em tradução literal, significa `minificado`, ou, de forma menos técnica e mais coloquial, `compactado`.

Esses tipos de arquivos comumente têm suas variáveis e nomenclaturas abreviadas porque o seu destino não são olhos humanos, mas sim idiomas maquinários. Isso significa que, `$variavel` ou `nomeDeFuncao()` podem se tornar, respectivamente, `$v` e `f()`. Essa prática, quando usada em um arquivo grande e com bastante demanda, faz com que ele seja menos consumidor de recursos – o  arquivo fica mais leve, a banda para consumi-lo será menor e a leitura será feita com mais velocidade.

O *ideal*  é que utilizemos arquivos `.min` quando fizermos o *deploy* da nossa aplicação. Em outras palavras, quando disponibilizamos a nossa aplicação para o mundo é que nós compactamos os arquivos `.js` – os `.css`  também podem ser minificados. Como eu disse, a linguagem de um arquivo compactado fica mais maquinária e não tem como foco o olho humano, portanto, quando nós disponibilizarmos uma aplicação, a necessidade é que a máquina faça uma leitura (ou download, como preferir) mais rápida e o objetivo não é a edição ou modificação do código, mesmo que terceiros tenham acesso à ele.

Arquivos **sem o sufixo `.min`** são geralmente para *desenvolvimento*. Isso porque, na maioria das vezes, o seu código é limpo e ele está na forma no qual foi escrito: às vezes com comentários e documentação. Lembrando que, nem sempre um arquivo sem o sufixo em questão significa que ele **não** está compactado.

Portanto, **não se preocupe**. Se você escrever JavaScript, faça-o do seu jeito – com comentários, documentação e variáveis com nomes "temporários", porque no fim das contas, quando a sua aplicação for para produção, isso não vai fazer diferença se o arquivo for compactado.

**Mas atenção**, tenha sempre boas práticas em mente – não é porque você tem o poder da *minificação* que deve escrever o que quiser. Acostume-se com o jeito certo que quando isso virar hábito, você será um *expert*.

Para minificação, os meus preferidos são:

- [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)
- [jsCompress](http://jscompress.com/)

E não se esqueça que linguagens como `ruby` (com `rails`) e `C#/MVC` (com `.NET`) tem a capacidade de fazer isso nativamente com os seus compressores internos.

Comment: +1 pra você por mencionar que algumas plataformas (tal como o .Net) possuem ferramentas para fazer isso de forma automática, e sobre recomendar manter boas práticas.

Answer (score 3):

O arquivo file.min.js, possui as mesmas informações do outro, porém de forma minificada, como assim?
Para evitar ficar carregando arquivos de java script ou css pesado para a página, no minifier(arquivo min) são removidas tabulações, espaços em branco, afim de diminuir o tamanho do arquivo e melhorar o desempenho e velocidade da página durante o carregamento, pois o arquivo fica mais leve.

Answer (score 2):

De uma forma geral um aqrquivo `.min.js` é ideal que seja utilizado no ambiente de produção, por se tratar de um arquivo minificado, ou seja, todas as identações são removidos para reduzir o tamanho físico do arquivo, fazendo com que o mesmo seja carregado mais rápidamente, enquanto o arquivo não minificado conta com todas as identações para melhorrar a leitura do arquivo em um ambiente de desenvolvimento.

### Eu posso utilizar um arquivo não minificado no ambiente de produção?

Com certeza pode, porém em alguns casos o tempo de requisição de um arquivo não minificado chega a ser 3 a 4 vezes maior que o arquivo minificado.

### Como minificar um arquivo javascript?

Uma das feramentas mais utilizada para validação e minificação de arquivos `.js` hoje é o [**grunt**](http://tableless.com.br/grunt-voce-deveria-estar-usando/).
Outra possibilidade de minificação de arquivos é o [**ant**](http://www.milfont.org/tech/2008/12/16/minificacao-de-javascript-com-ant-task/), porém recomendo estudar um pouco sobre estas e outras ferramentas para fazer a melhor escolha para a sua realidade.