# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de minificar scripts JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, otimização, minificação

E quais minificadores posso usar?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre o uso de arquivos .js e .min.js?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15019/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-uso-de-arquivos-js-e-min-js)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Vantagem

O ganho é bastante óbvio, o arquivo fica menor e carrega mais rápido. Alguns vão dizer que fica mais difícil ler o código e ser reaproveitado, mas não acho isto uma vantagem real e existem técnicas melhores.

## Desvantagem

Não há desvantagem de fato. Claro que se você ainda está desenvolvendo precisa *debugar* não vai usar a versão minificada. O máximo que pode-se dizer é que existe um passo extra para fazer a minificação, mas isto pode ser automatizado e não chega ser uma desvantagem. Alguns poderão achar outras desvantagens exotéricas mas estamos falando de situações reais. Obviamente usar um minificador agressivo e inseguro não é uma boa ideia aí é bem desvantajoso.

## É útil mesmo?

Vale para todos os arquivos texto que possuem caracteres redundantes usados apenas para facilitar a leitura humana. Em conteúdo gerado dinamicamente não costuma compensar a aplicação desta técnica pelo tempo que o servidor gastará para minificar cada resultado enviado.

Esta técnica pode ser usada junto com a técnica de compressão de dados. Não confundir as duas, minificar não é a mesma coisa que comprimir.

Alguns podem se perguntar se a compressão não é uma técnica muito melhor e que até dispensaria a minificação. Isto é verdade mas nem todos os clientes aceitam compressão e aí você fica sem técnica alguma. Qualquer cliente que entenda bem os padrões web entende o arquivo minificado. O ganho pode não ser fabuloso mas é importante.

## Melhores minificadores

Qualquer minificador minimamente (eu não perdi a oportunidade :) ) bem feito vai obter um resultado razoável, a não ser que seja um muito ingênuo e feito por quem não sabe o que está fazendo (aí você tem problemas até maiores), terá uma ganho bom. Eu duvido que exista grande diferença entre os mais diversos. Faça uma avaliação real usando alguns deles e veja qual dá melhor resultado em seu caso.

Eu evitaria usar um desconhecido, ninguém sabe se ele é confiável. A pior coisa que você pode fazer é usar um minificador que quebra seu código.

Alguns conhecidos bem testados:

- [Uglyfy JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)
- [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)
- [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
- [MS AJAX Minifier](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/)
- [JavaScript Minifier](http://javascript-minifier.com/)

Alguns destes servem para CSS também. Abaixo alguns para CSS que também podem trabalhar com JS.

- [CSSMin](http://www.phpied.com/cssmin-js/)
- [YUICompressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) - está desatualizado mas ainda é bom.
- [MinifyCSS](http://www.minifycss.com/)
- [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [Minify](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [CSSCompressor](https://csscompressor.net/)
- [CSSO](https://github.com/css/csso)

E obviamente pode-se minificar HTML (quando raramente compensa):

- [HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/)
- [Minify Code](http://minifycode.com/)

Teste eles com coisas suas e veja qual se sai melhor. Não espere grandes diferenças.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: reduz o tamanho, mas o tempo que o navegador terá para interpretar(dependendo da quantidade de arquivos js's um site carregar), não aumenta também, ou estar minificado ou não é irrelevante quando se trata do interpretador de JS?

Comment: A minificação não vai afetar isto, na verdade pode até haver um ganho irrisório porque tem menos caracteres para *parsear*. A descompressão já produziria um *overhad* mas compensaria. Afinal vários arquivos usados no desenvolvimento web são comprimidos por padrão. E mesmo este custo extra é pequeno perto do ganho. A compressão no servidor poderia gerar um custo extra que não compense, por isso não é muito recomendado comprimir conteúdo dinâmico (o estático comprime uma vez e não cada vez que é requisitado). Note que custo extra em servidor é perigoso, em cliente só se for algo absurdo.

Comment: @bigown usar o UglifyJS: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS seria de grande ganho para minha aplicação?

Comment: Agora entendi a pergunta adicionou que você tinha colocado, você não queria saber sobre *frameworks* e sim sobre minificadores. Vou reededitar para colocar isto de volta mas sem pedir opinião. Editei a resposta para incluir esta informação. Mas não vou dar minha opinião sobre ele. Sei que ele é bom, mas não afirmaria categoricamente que é o melhor.

Comment: @bigown obrigado pelo retorno

Comment: @bigown ficou parecendo que a lista de minificadores que você passou são ruins, pois acabou de falar dos que quebram o código... O.o

Comment: @KaduAmaral melhorou?

Comment: Sei lá to só especulando, já dei o voto mesmo. Ficou boa a explicação, mas esse trecho tá meio estranho: `um minificador que quebra seu código. Alguns conhecidos`... :S Coloca só "Minificadores Conhecidos" e acho que está ótimo rsrsrs...

Answer (score 0):

A grande e maior vantagem esta no consumo de dados, claro dependendo do cenário não temos grandes vantagens contudo dependendo da sua aplicação faz muito sentido.

**Como assim?**

Imagine o seguinte cenario temos o seguinte código:

```
function FuncaoComNomeGrande(parametroComNomeGrande) {
    const VariavelComNomeGrande = "Essa string não vai ser minificada";
    console.log("Essa string não vai ser minificada" + parametroComNomeGrande);
}

FuncaoComNomeGrande("Essa string tambem não vai ser minificada");
```

Este código tem 275 caracteres que em [bytes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) da ~278 é diferente por que alguns caracteres consomem mais bits que outros por exemplo o **Ç**.

Este código minificado ficaria mais o menos assim:

```
function f(a){console.log("Essa string não vai ser minificada"+a)}f("Essa string tambem não vai ser minificada")
```

Com 112 caracteres que em bytes fica 114 ~bytes. Claro neste cenário usei um exemplo forçando um pouco a barra definindo nomes gigantes para variáveis e funções. Na vida real existe sim um grande ganho mas nem sempre é tão alto assim.

Onde está a **vantagem** em um tamanho menor?

1. Consome menos [trafégo com internet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A1fego_web).
2. Consome menos [armazenamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospedagem_de_s%C3%ADtios_web), ou seja menos gasto com hospedagem.
3. É mais rapido. Quanto menor o tráfego de dados menor é a [perda de pacotes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss).

Uma coisa muito legal sobre minificar as coisas que também pode ser uma **desvantagem** dependendo do ponto de vista é que muitos minificadores uma vez minificado jamais conseguirá voltar a versão original. Isso ocorre porque no processo de minificação muitas partes do seu código acabam sumindo.

Existem muitos minificadores com diferentes algoritmos, todos eles usam [algoritmos de compressão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress%C3%A3o_de_dados) que é um tópico muito legal de se estudar. Deixo um [vídeo aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEQRz7BmGtA) que não está em pt-br mas é um dos mais legais que vi sobre o assunto. Abaixo os mais famosos que conheço:

- [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js)
- [terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser)

Minificar eles manualmente pode ser uma tarefa ineficiente para isso temos empacotadores e automatizadores de tarefas como [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) como [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).