# Qual a diferença de arquivo js com .min e sem .min?

Tags: javascript, minificação

Qual a **diferença de arquivos *JavaScript*** que contém `.min` (por exemplo `jQuery.min.js`)
e o arquivo sem o `.min` (por exemplo `jQuery.js`)?

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88058/101. Veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100977/101

Comment: @bigown acho que a que mais se encaixa em duplicata é com esta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15019/3635

Comment: Se alguém estiver vendo esta pergunta em busca de melhorar o tempo do carregamento de uma página ou sistema web. Deve-se considerar que, embora a "minificação" diminua consideravelmente o tamanho dos recursos JavaScript e também CSS, uma abordagem mais vantajosa é servir recursos compactos com gzip.

Comment: Já respondida em [Qual a **diferença** entre o uso de arquivos **.js** e .min.js?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15019/70).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

É muito comum bibliotecas (ou de modo geral ficheiros grandes) terem uma versão `.min`, que quer dizer minificado, comprimido.

Por exemplo um ficheiro de JavaScript pode ser assim:

```
var jogadores = equipaA + equipaB;
```

e a versão minificada ser assim:

```
var a = b + c;
```

Isso é feito por um programa que comprime ficheiros de JavaScript e que tem como função fazer o código menor diminuindo o tamanho do ficheiro, fazendo-o mais leve para download. Nesse caso o programa pode transformar essa linha de exemplo em cima numa linha mais curta, muitas vezes com grandes diferenças de tamanho.

O programa gera ou muda o nome de variáveis para ele ficar mais pequeno, mas mantendo a funcionalidade.

No caso do jQuery comparando a [versão minificada](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js) com a [versão não minificada](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js) (também chamada, "de desenvolvimento"/developer ou não-comprimida) a diferença é clara:

> **Versão comprimida:** 104382 caracteres
>   **Versão não-comprimida:** 298444 caracteres (praticamente 3x maior)

Comment: E eu que pensava que era só remoção de espaços e quebra de linhas que minimizava um arquivo dessa forma.

Comment: Embora seja obvio faltou listar a vantagem do não-comprimido. O "normal" permite uma melhor leitura do código. Modificar algo no "min" torna-se mais difícil, porque não possui os nomes "corretos" e nem comentários sobre o que está sendo feito. Então use o "min" nos projetos, mas leia e faça alterações necessárias no "normal".

Answer (score 5):

A versão minificada (`.min`) é resultado de um processo chamado `minification`, que remove quebras de linha, espaços e comentários desnecessários.

Este processo não modifica nomes de variáveis.

O processo que modifica o nome das variáveis é outro e se chama `uglification`.

Comment: Nossa agora sim, depois do que você disse faz sentido....Sempre estranhei os projetos que utilizam o Gruntfile o nome da `task` não ser `jsmin` ou algo do tipo como do css e sim ser `uglify`, vlw cara :)

Comment: Não é verdade que um ficheiro `.min` tem os nomes das variáveis intactas. Vê por exemplo a versão [1.12.3.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js) do jQuery. É um ficheiro `.min` e tem os nomes das variáveis modificadas.

Comment: Sim, acredito que a maioria das bibliotecas optam por ambos processos.