# Como é a leitura de sentenças com virgula em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, minificação

Hoje estava testando [minificar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124006/14213) meu código e fiquei em duvida quanto a conversão

#### Código Original

```
Loader = (function(Configure){

    var CurrentAction = null;
    var loaded = [];

    loader = function(){}

    loader.prototype = {
        check : function(action){
            var _return = false;
            if(CurrentAction == null || Configure.get('reload')){
                loaded.push(action);
                _return = true;
            }

            if(CurrentAction != action && loaded.indexOf(action) == -1){
                loaded.push(action);
                _return = true;
            }
            CurrentAction = action;
            return _return;
        }
    }

    return new loader();
}(Configure));
```

#### Código Minificado

```
Loader = function(e) {
    var n = null,
        r = [];
    return loader = function() {}, loader.prototype = {
        check: function(o) {
            var u = !1;
            return (null == n || e.get("reload")) && (r.push(o), u = !0), n != o && -1 == r.indexOf(o) && (r.push(o), u = !0), n = o, u
        }
    }, new loader
}(Configure);
```

#### Duvida

- Como se lê esse código com virgulas?

#### Adendo

Eu ate entendo ele não executar `(r.push(o), u = !0)` se `-1 == r.indexOf(o)` já ter gerado `false`, mas eu não compreendo quando é executado o que vem apos a virgula, `n = o, u`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é uma técnica de `precedência de operador`, e o nome de desse operador é `operador de vírgula (comma operator)` ou também conhecido como operador de avaliação múltipla.

Ele funciona da seguinte forma, ele avalia ou cálcula todos as expressões passadas separadas por vírgula da esquerda para a direita e retorna a última expressão passada.

Segue um exemplo:

```
var expr1 = 10 + 10,//Cálcula
    expr2 = 100 * 10,//Cálcula
    expr3 = 10 == "10",//Avalia
    expr4 = expr1 === expr2 && expr3;//Essa expressão expr4 que será retornada.

expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4;
```

Esse operador é mais usado quando você quer usar mais de uma expressão em um local onde normalmente se usaria uma só.

Normalmente esse operador é mais usado em loops `for`, por exemplo:

```
var vetor = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]
];

for (var i = 0, j = 2; i < vetor.length; i++, j--) {
   console.log(vetor[i][j]);
}
```

Agora em relação ao seu código minificado, o que é retornado depois da vírgula é um valor booleano, que é essa variável `u`, que no seu código original representa sua variável `_return`.

```
var u = !1;
```

Igual a:

```
var _return = false;
```

E:

```
u = !0
```

Igual a:

```
_return = true;
```

Obs.: Essa expressão `!1` é igual a `false` e `!0` igual a `true`.

#### Analiando a conversão (Guilherme Lautert)

`(null == n || e.get("reload")) && (r.push(o), u = !0)`

- `(r.push(o), u = !0)` esta parte do código sempre ira retonar `true`, contudo ela só é executada se a sentença anterior tbm for verdadeira
- `(null == n || e.get("reload"))` é uma verificação real, que caso seja `false` ignora a proxima sentença pois se trata de um `&&`

`n != o && -1 == r.indexOf(o) && (r.push(o), u = !0)`

- Similar ao anterior

`n = o`

- Esta é a parte que é sempre executada `CurrentAction = action;`

`u`

- Como comentado a ultima parte é retornada, esta que seria o `_return`

Comment: Só um adendo para que ninguém confunda: a vírgula em `var n = null, r = [];` é outra coisa: faz parte da sintaxe do `var`, não é o *comma operator*.

Comment: Compreendi, e analisando novamente o código ficou mais claro. Se não se importa gostaria de acrescentar alguns deleta-lhes.

Comment: Ok, tudo bem, pode acrescentar.

Answer (score 2):

O que está ali na frente de `return` é uma sequência de expressão, e a última expressão (onde foi declarado o identificador `u`) vai ser retornada para o próprio statement `return`. Uma sequência de expressão vai para blocos, grupos (`(...)`) e outros lugares também, não apenas aí.

Em uma sequência de expressão não são declarados statements, somente expressões; Já, se você o declarar o statement `var` (`let` ou `const`), você não inicia uma sequência de expressão, mesmo se usar vírgulas, porém `var` só vai em blocos de comandos (como eu disse, statements não são declarados em sequência de expressão) e em outros lugares, por exemplo, nos argumentos do `for` que são separados por semicolons (`;`).

---

E outra, as chavetas declaradas depois das funções e depois dos statements `for`, `while`, `with`, etc, elas iniciam um bloco, que pode ter um novo escopo de variáveis dependendo do tipo. Se essas chavetas não são declaradas, é possível declarar apenas uma sequência de expressão, e também é possível declarar o statement `var`. Exemplo: `if(true) var a, b;`

*Observação*: `try`, `catch` e `finally` são statements que necessitam que as chavetas sejam declaradas porque o interpretador dos navegadores requerem, atualmente. Principalmente `function...(...)`.