# Sentença separada por vírgula num IF Javascript teria qual finalidade? "if (1, 2) {}"

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Por acidente quando eu estava alterando um código Javascript que eu fiz, coloquei uma vírgula ao invés do `||` em uma expressão `if`.

Eu alterei `if (that.busy || that.completed) return;` para `if (that.busy, that.completed) return;` sem querer, e notei que não gerou nenhum erro de sintaxe.

Além disso, fiz outros testes que também não geraram erros:

```js
var a = 1,   
    b = 2;

if (a, b) {
    console.log('a', 'b');
}

if (1, b) {
   console.log(1, 'b');
}


if (1, 2, 3) {
     console.log(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Sendo assim, fiquei sem entender porquê de o Javascript aceitar isso. Mas provavelmente isso deve ter a finalidade.

Gostaria de saber para que isso serve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neste caso a tua condição `if` avalia somente o ultimo caso, como uma normal operação com [operador `,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), ou seja uma `Sequence Expression`.
Há uma outra pergunta/resposta que [fala sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141680/129).

O que acontece no exemplo

```
if (1, 2, 3) {
     console.log(1, 2, 3);
}
```

é:

```
if (3) console.log(1, 2, 3);
```

pois diz a defenição do operador `,`:

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.
>
> O operador `,` avalia as expressões dos seus operandos, da esquerda para a direita, e retorna o valor do último operando.

Um exemplo mais claro seria talvez:

```
if (1, 2, false) {
     console.log(1, 2, 3);
}
```

que nunca entra dentro do `if` pois a condição retorna `false`.
Para ser correto talvez o ideal fosse parentesis duplos: `if ((1, 2, false))` para não misturar a sintaxe do `if` com a sintaxe do operador `,`, mas parece funcionar bem esta maneira "atalho".

Há uma ferramenta excelente para ler o AST de JavaScript. [Neste caso](https://astexplorer.net/#/QdcRfdxf3q) pode ler-se a seguinte árvore abstrata de sintaxe:

```
{
      "type": "IfStatement",
      "start": 4,
      "end": 55,
      "test": {
        "type": "SequenceExpression",
        "start": 8,
        "end": 15,
        "expressions": [ ... os operandos ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pra mim foi mais fácil entender assim:

```
var test = 5;
if(test+=5,test-=6,test==10){
    console.log(test);
}else{
    console.log(test);
}
```

Qualquer coisa antes da última expressão é executado, porém o `if` só usa a última expressão para decidir se o resultado é verdadeiro ou falso.

Comment: Acho que essa última frase precisa ser melhor elaborada. Não quis editar pra não ser invasivo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pode editar meu português não muito bom.