# É possível usar funções dentro de uma condição?

Tags: javascript, condição

Estava analisando uns sites na internet quando me deparei com o seguinte trecho:

```
if (console.log(i), i && void 0 !== i.name) {
    // code here...
}
```

Eu testei isso:

```
var i = {name: "mizuk"};
if (console.log(i), i && void 0 !== i.name) {
    console.log("condição verdadeira!");
}
```

O que eu entendi do código foi:

```
// se 'i' não estiver vazio e 'i.name' não tiver o mesmo valor e tipo 
// que 'undefined' faça:
```

O que eu quero saber é:

-> onde entra 'console.log(i)' nisso tudo?, ele faz parte da condição ou ele foi simplesmente chamado no meio da sentença?

-> se ele foi chamado, isso é algo comum ou é uma gambiarra?

-> se é algo comum, eu posso executar outras funções desse jeito?

Agradeço desde já toda a ajuda.

Comment: Relacionado: [Sentença separada por vírgula num IF Javascript teria qual finalidade? “if (1, 2) {}”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169208)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1** - console.log está ali pra exibir o que foi comparado no if, porém, pode ser substituido por outras funções.
Nesse exemplo essa linha significa, executar a função(console.log) e comparar, se verdadeiro, entrar no `if`.

**2** - Comum ou gambiarra, não vejo muito casos que isso vá ser realmente necessário.

**3** - Sim, pode, como no exemplo a baixo:

```js
var i = {name: "mizuk"};
if (concatenarEExibir(i), i && void 0 !== i.name) {
    console.log("condição verdadeira!");
}
function concatenarEExibir(i){
  console.log('Nome:' + i.name);
}
```

**OBS:**

No exemplo usei o comando console.log mesmo, porém pode haver qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 1):

O `console.log(i)` não tem nenhuma função prática nesse `if` a não ser imprimir o valor no console.

Sem o `console.log` o `if` ficaria apenas:

```
if(i && void 0 !== i.name) {
    console.log("condição verdadeira!");
}
```

A condição é verdadeira porque `i` é *true* (um objeto existente) e `void 0` (*undefined*) é diferente em valor e tipo de `i.name`.

Não sei qual seria a função de usar `console.log` dentro de um `if` (se é que exista uma). Primeira vez que vejo isso. Até porque a mensagem exibida no console não aparece na página, ou seja, não tem efeito prático, a não ser para desenvolvedores.

Provável que esse `console.log` seja apenas para checar o valor da variável, isso é até comum na hora do desenvolvimento, mas eu prefiro usar fora do `if` porque depois fica até mais fácil de remover a linha:

```
var i = {name: "mizuk"};
console.log(i);
if (i && void 0 !== i.name) {
    console.log("condição verdadeira!");
}
```

Comment: Acredito q console.log seja meio inútil no final mesmo, mas como da pra executar uma função no mesmo lugar, pode servir pra economizar uma linha, mas também não consegui ver utilidade real.

Answer (score 1):

A função `console.log()` serve para mostrar algo no console do navegador.

A pesar de ser uma função, ela não dá retorno, o Javascript possui algumas formas de Display, o `Console.log()` é uma delas.

O correto é usar o `Console.log()` separado da lógica do código. Incluir na lógica do código é gambiarra e vai dar trabalho para mais tarde pois terá que tirar.