# Minify código HTML

Tags: html, desempenho, minificação

É normal vemos arquivos em JavaScript minificados, para ganho de performance.

Hoje vemos alguns sites que minificam tudo, inclusive o próprio código **HTML**, como por exemplo [este daqui.](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/) (use a opção de exibir código fonte do seu navegador)

Com base nisso, eu pergunto: **Realmente vale a pena ter trabalho para minificar o arquivo HTML?**

Se sim, até que ponto o trabalho de minificar o arquivo supera a performance perdida?

> Caso o site não esteja disponível, a minificação que me refiro, é simplesmente retirar os espaços, e não "transformar" o código.

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista tem pessoas que enchem de tanto Javascript e CSS junto ao html ao invés de colocar nos arquivos e escrevem tantas tags html que poderiam ser feito de maneira mais simples e ainda sim obter o mesmo resultado, acaba que minificar o HTML é uma solução pra resolver problemas que nós mesmos criamos, ou seja poderia ser resolvido apena organizando o código e minificar seria quase dispensável.

Comment: Acho que já está respondido em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100977/101

Comment: Eu editei errado sua pergunta e acabaram aceitando, desculpa. O link não funciona sem "http://" e ele não navega para o que você quer com "http://"...

Comment: @DanielDutra é que view-source: é um pseudo-protocolo do chrome e derivados, o sistema do site não reconhece como link. Mas eu apelei pro "método primitivo" e pus o link original e a recomendação em texto mesmo, assim funciona em qq lugar :) - deletei o meu comentário de cima e jajá deleto esse. De qualquer forma, é muito bom que você ajude o site. Pequenos "acidentes" podem acontecer, mas a comunidade está aí pra revisar, então fique tranquilo.

Comment: `É possível abstrair certos elementos de tal forma que o texto específico que será usado para montar o HTML nem é de conhecimento do programador que está montando aquela página` Este trecho da minha resposta fala de algo que é muito fácil no Razor do ASP.Net.

Comment: @DanielDutra Obrigado para alertar, foi um erro meu.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado por editar a pergunta, foi um erro meu

Comment: @bigown A sua resposta está muito ampla, e não abrange a pergunta. Minha pergunta eu falo especificamente do **HTML** gerado. Se observarmos as ferramentas de desenvolvedor, podemos ver que o comportamento é diferente entre a página (HTML, etc) do CSS/JS

Comment: @Randrade tudo bem, mas a resposta está lá, não está? Você quer que eu repita o que eu já escrevi lá, aqui?

Comment: @bigown Infelizmente, sua resposta não me responde. Você safa sobre "transformar" HTML, o que é diferente do que é apresentado aqui. Minificação e "transformação" são coisas distintas, e creio que você sabe disse. Peço desculpas se a pergunta não está clara, irei tentar melhorá-lá.

Comment: @bigown Editei a pergunta, espero que tenha ficado melhor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro, minificação é um ato de transformação. Se alguém não sabe, transformar é alterar, mudar a forma. Não há nenhuma definição do que está se referindo. O que muda é transformado.

Segundo, esta é uma pergunta de boa prática. Pode não conter as palavras, mas é isto o que pede. Por isso já começo dizendo que depende do caso. Vou colocar linhas gerais aqui, mas cada caso precisa ser analisando como único e a decisão deve ser tomada com dados reais para aquela situação.

Diversas vezes vi a situação não ser a esperada ou até mesmo mudar. Já participei de projeto que começou bem minificando e depois com um padrão diferente de tráfego teve que desligar para obter melhor resultado.

Vou considerar que o minificador usado tem qualidade.

## HTML estático

É claro que minificar um HTML estático, assim como JS os CSS, é sempre vantajoso. Você faz o processo uma vez e tem o ganho todas as vezes que ele for usado.

Então este é outro depende. A página será estática? (não significa imutável) Manda ver. Mesmo que o HTML permita uma minificação menor do que JS ou CSS permite, ainda assim, há ganho.

Dá trabalho fazer isto? Se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo, nenhum em específico. Claro que que tem que organizar tudo. Tem ferramentas que ajudam. Mas se a pessoa chegou se preocupar com isto, resolveu analisar os dados, automatizar o processo será o de menos.

Considere como HTML estático as **páginas** usadas com tecnologia [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

#### Mas eu uso compressão de dados no servidor

A compressão realmente feita da forma correta realmente torna desnecessário o uso da minificação (de tudo, não só HTML). Mas nem sempre podemos garantir que a compressão será feita. Podemos usar um servidor que não tem esta capacidade habilitada, ou estar comunicando com um navegador que não tem capacidade de receber os arquivos comprimidos. Nestes casos a minificação ajuda.

Mesmo nos casos onde a compressão é ativa, haverá mais ganho com a minificação, bem pouco, mas terá.

## HTML Dinâmico

Quando falamos de páginas dinâmicas (criadas sob demanda) a coisa já fica mais complicada. Depende de muitos fatores e não poderei elencar todos. Pode passar pelo padrão de tráfego, a capacidade de processamento do servidor e a ociosidade dele, se há restrição de tráfego ou o custo é muito alto, se as páginas costumam permanecer muito em cache ou não, se o servidor de aplicação web ajuda ou não, etc.

O maior ganho quando se pensa em tráfego costuma dar-se pela compressão realizada pelo servidor web em acordo com o navegador. Se isto não for possível a minificação ajuda. Ela diminui a quantidade de tráfego e pode reduzir ligeiramente o tempo de carga da página (em geral outros fatores costumam ser mais importantes).

Para minificar todas páginas antes de sair do servidor há um custo de processamento. É muito comum precisar de um servidor mais poderoso para executar isto bem que tem custo monetário maior, é comum ser maior do que o ganho que terá por diminuir o tráfego.

Outro custo é o tempo para processar a minificação. Você ganha tempo trafegando menos dados, mas perde preparando-os.

Como saber quando é o ponto que compensa? Só medindo. É comum não compensar, mas não afirmo isso para todas situações.

Nem vou falar dos casos que pode haver ganho, mas ele ser irrelevante. E a maioria dos casos é irrelevante, portanto, faça o mais simples.

Em páginas dinâmicas costuma-se desligar até a compressão que pode dar mais ganhos. Imagine se a minificação, que costuma custar mais caro e ter resultados inferiores, vai compensar.

## Como funciona a minificação

Entenda que o processo de minificação passa por uma análise da página, é preciso fazer pelo menos um *lexing*, e provavelmente um *parsing* básico ou mais completo. Mesmo que queira tirar só os espaços precisa entender cada parte do código para não tirar espaços de onde não deve.

É claro que tirar só espaços terá um processamento mais curto, mas também terá menos ganhos. Uma minificação mais completa pode demorar um pouco mais para processar, mas gerará um *stream* menor.

Feito o *parsing*, por que não tratar todas situações possíveis? O grosso do custo é percorrer o arquivo, a geração do minificado em maior ou menor grau vai mudar pouco o custo total de processamento (a não ser que se pretenda fazer uma análise mais "inteligente" e cortar ao extremo).

Qual compensa mais? Não sei. Ninguém pode afirmar isto sem o caso real. Uma afirmação para um lado ou outro soará como "boa prática".

Eu acho que se é pra minificar que faça o melhor possível, mas não aplicaria isto sem analisar o caso real. Vou chutar que minificar pouco compensa bem pouco, ou nada. Melhor minificar com todo potencial que esteja disponível.

Ao mesmo tempo que nestes casos de páginas dinâmicas, é quase certo que eu não minificaria, a não ser durante a própria geração da página, quando isto for pertinente.

Não sei se podemos chamar de minificação a geração da página já minificada, mas certamente o resultado gerado será minificado. Quando uma página é gerada *on-the-fly* é possível, em algumas circunstâncias, já gerar seu corpo bem enxuto, afinal não interessará para nenhum humano. Claro que há casos onde a geração será feita em cima de gabaritos escritos por humanos, nestes talvez seja interessante a minificação no gabarito. Esta parece ser uma técnica mais adequada nestes casos, mas não entrarei em detalhes porque não parece ser o foco da pergunta.

## Conclusão

Analise seu caso, faça acompanhamento. Se achar que não compensa fazer isto, então siga a regra do HTML estático deve ser minificado e o dinâmico, não. Se acha que qualquer coisa pode ser trabalhosa demais, então para de se preocupar com isso, de fato o ganho não é excepcional e só trará vantagens reais em sites de grande movimento.

Eu não sei como a página de exemplo foi gerada, então eu não sei se eles fizeram o melhor ou não. Mesmo que seja gerada dinamicamente, eu consigo gerá-la minificada e compensar. Se vai valer o trabalho que eu vou ter para fazer isto, depende do caso de uso específico.

A essência desta pergunta já foi respondida em [Compilação/Minificação de arquivos HTML, CSS e nome de classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100977/101), o que me faz pensar que a pergunta é de fato duplicata (afinal lendo as respostas lá postadas, esclarece a dúvida colocada aqui).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sua resposta me chama atenção para dois fatos. Você fala que minificar é transformar, logo, da a entender que se eu transformar algo para maior, entrará em seu conceito, o que não é verdade. Existem tipos de minificações, mesmo que não possuírem uma definição exata (ou eu não encontrei). Apenas remover espaços é um tipo, remover comentários, outro. Em outras palavras, se diminuiu o tamanho do arquivo, com o mesmo funcionando, podemos "chamar" de minificação. Mas a pergunta não é sobre o conceito, isso está na pergunta que você linkou.

Comment: Outra questão, é que você fala **"É claro que minificar um HTML estático, assim como JS os CSS é sempre vantajoso."** Minificar HTML pode gerar problemas ao ser compilado. Você comenta isso em sua resposta, mas se a pessoa não ler tudo por preguiça, ou outro motivo, ficará com uma "ideia" incompleta.

Comment: No demais, sua resposta está boa, mas não atinge o que eu queria. Eu queria algo mais técnico, com exemplos de ganhos reais, ou não. Mas isso foi erro meu ao elaborar a pergunta, não especificando. Editá-la agora também não é mais viável, pois sua resposta é boa, e gerará conhecimento para o site.

Comment: Minificar é necessariamente transformar, transformar pode ser em vários sentidos. O fato de uma coisa ser verdade em um sentido, não quer dizer que seja obrigado ser na direção contrária. Transformar, portanto não é minificar. De fato existem alguns tipos de minificação. Eu respondo pras pessoas que não são preguiçosas, as outras já estão com a mente toda estragada :) A pergunta como você queria provavelmente seria muito ampla.