# Como remover todos os comentários de vários documentos PHP de uma só vez?

Tags: php, html, comentários

Como remover todos os comentários de vários documentos PHP de uma só vez?

Comment: talvez o gulp ou grunt tenha algo assim. Ou então no `Ctrl + H` passando uma expressão regular numa IDE que tenha essa função disponível

Comment: Pode usar uma minificação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100977/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128042/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88058/101

Comment: @Maniero, confundi no título do tópico. Não se trata de HTML, e sim de PHP. Porém, a minificação da codificação funcionou perfeitamente. Utilizei este site: http://www.cuho.eu/php-minify/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal é usar um software de minificação. A única forma de fazer totalmente automática e de forma simples é assim. Mesmo usando um editor que aceite expressões regulares, não é fácil criar uma expressão simples, imagina uma complexa porque não é só pegar o padrão, tem uma série de padrões que vale ou não vale, inclusive porque o comentário pode estar dentro de uma *string*, pode estar aninhado, pode fazer parte de código de outra linguagem embutida na principal e outras formas que o que parece comentário não é

*Parsear* código é complexo demais para deixar para uma ferramenta muito precária. Veja mais em: [Comentários pesam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199201/101).

[Exemplos de minificadores para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113947/101). Nos comentários tem para HTML/CSS/HTML.