# Dúvida javascript function t(n,t,i,r)

Tags: javascript

Costumo ver o código fonte das páginas e nunca entendi isso.

```
function dt(n,t,i,r)
```

O que significam essas letras?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provavelmente, esse foi um código gerado por um minificador de Javascript.

Ao usar minificadores, além de ganhar em performance por conta de diminuir o tamanho dos códigos, você ainda tem a vantagem de ter seu código ofuscado (técnica usada para diminuir a compreensão da lógica do que foi escrito).

Um exemplo é o código gerado pelo Yui Compressor.

Código original:

```
(function () {

    function StackOverflow(language) {

        var user, age;

        user = 'Wallace';
        age = 26;
    }

})()
```

Código minificado:

```
(function(){function a(d){var c,b;c="Wallace";b=26;}})();
```

Observe que o nome das variáveis foram trocados por apenas letras, como no seu exemplo.

Comment: +1. Curti o exemplo de minificação. Gosto muito de exemplos pq fica fácil visualizar as coisas. Agora tenho mais uma pergunta que talvez vc possa me responder complementando sua resposta. Porque nesse código tem esses parênteses externos envolta da função e os dois vazios no fim?  (function(){...})()

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre isso é uma "função autoexecutável". É uma função que é chamada ao mesmo tempo em que está declarada. Usamos isso para proteger o escopo e evitar que as variáveis fiquem "soltas" no escopo global.

Comment: Eu ia morrer sem saber disso! Sempre achava bizarro esses parênteses em torno da função em alguns códigos. Muito obrigado pela explicação! Se eu pudesse dava +2 na resposta. :D

Answer (score 18):

É uma funçâo javascript com nome `dt` e tem 4 parametros `n`, `t`, `i` e `r`. Ela aparece com esses nomes porque é costume ser feita a minimização de código para reduzir o tamanho do ficheiro, poupando dessa forma trafego e ganhando eventualmente algum tempo no carregamento da página.

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88058/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-minificar-scripts-js/88060#88060)

Também é possível que a funçâo tenha sido obfuscada e nao minimizada. O processo de obfuscacao dá possibilidade de manter o código secreto sendo por isso de dificil interpretacao por seres mortais, como nós humanos.

Comment: Esses são 4 argumentos ou 4 parâmetros, sempre tenho essa duvida de quem é quem nas funções...

Comment: @MagicHat Depende de como redigir a frase. Os argumentos sao recebidos pela funcao. O chamador da funcao passa argumentos á funcao. Mas a funcao tem parametros e nao argumentos. É correto eu dizer que ela recebe 4 argumentos mas nao é correcto dizer que ela tem 4 argumentos. Teria que dizer que ela tem 4 parametros. [veja a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/) e [esta também](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163079/quem-%C3%A9-quem-no-uso-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es/163085#163085)

Comment: Vlw man, eu já tinha lidos essas 2 e mais umas outras (algumas vezes), mas somente agora as coisas começam a parecer fazer sentido.

Answer (score 7):

Acho que para complementar a resposta vale aqui uma explicação básica de como criar uma função em javascript.

1) se começa usando a palavra function seguida do nome que se quer para a função.

2) Abre parênteses, inclui-se os parâmetros que se quer utilizar na função separados por vírgula. Fecha parênteses.

3) Abre chaves para iniciar o código do bloco da função. Digita-se todo o código da função e no final pode-se usar a palavra return para retornar algum valor. Se não tiver return no final da função então a mesma não retorna nada e é chamado retorno do tipo void(vazio).

Exemplo 1: Função com retorno void:

```
<script>
function hello(nome)
{
    alert("Hello, " + nome + "! Welcome!");
}
</script>
```

Exemplo de chamada em um botão:

```
<input type="button" onclick="hello('Alexandre')" value="Clique">
```

Exemplo 2: Função com retorno.

```
<script>
// função com retorno
function soma(a,b)
{
    c = a + b;

    return c;
}

// Chamada da função, o retorno será guardado na variável minhasoma
minhasoma = soma(5,9);

alert(minhasoma);
</script>
```