# Como pegar, por referência, valores de string utilizando o PHP

Tags: php, ajax, referência

A forma que está:

```
var dados = $('#form').serialize(); // title=titulo&body=corpo
$.post("autosave.php", dados);
```

No PHP consigo pegar os valores por referência da seguinte forma:

`$title = &$_POST['title'];` e `$body= &$_POST['body'];`

Já quando tento fazer o mesmo para:

```
$.post("autosave.php", {'meus_dados': dados});
```

e no PHP:

```
$title = &$_POST['meus_dados']['title'];
$body  = &$_POST['meus_dados']['body'];
```

Obtenho os seguintes erros:

Primeiro erro:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in

Segundo erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor
>   overloaded objects in...

Comment: Existe a chave title? Deu um print_r para ter certeza?

Comment: Sim, certeza. `title=titulo&body=corpo` @rray

Comment: O `Form Data` no segundo caso será enviado assim: `meus_dados:title=sr&body=teste`, ou seja, no PHP apenas estará disponível o `$_POST['meus_dados']` que será uma string com o valor `title=sr&body=teste` e não um array como esperado. Faça o teste no PHP `print_r($_POST['meus_dados'])`.

Comment: Sim @FilipeMoraes, mas preciso pegar esses valores, individualmente, por referência.

Comment: pq precisa ser por referência?

Comment: rray, porque teoricamente, somente assim que estou conseguindo obter o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando a seguinte linha:

```
$.post("autosave.php", {'meus_dados': dados});
```

O `Form Data` da requisição HTTP será enviado assim:

> meus_dados:title=sr&body=teste

Ou seja, no PHP apenas estará disponível o `$_POST['meus_dados']` que será uma string com o valor `title=sr&body=teste` e não um array como esperado. Faça o teste no PHP `print_r($_POST)` e veja a estrutura do array `$_POST`.

Uma solução será utilizar o retorno da função `serializeArray` para criar um novo objecto:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Aplicando a solução:

```
var dados = $('#form').serializeObject();
$.post("autosave.php", {'meus_dados': dados});
```

Assim o `Form Data` da requisição HTTP terá o seguinte formato:

> meus_dados[title]:sr
>   meus_dados[body]:teste

No PHP o array `$_POST` terá os índices necessários para o seu script abaixo funcionar:

```
$title = &$_POST['meus_dados']['title'];
$body  = &$_POST['meus_dados']['body'];
```

Fonte (importante ler também os comentários): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/3636960