# Que aviso é esse no console usando AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou tentando rodar um simples código com angular e esse aviso apare no console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…    angular.js:38

Segue meu arquivo app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Meu controller:

```
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams){

$scope.pegaCep = function (data) {
    $http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$stateParams.cep).success(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });
 }

});
```

Sim, o aviso falar sobre a injeção errada do controller, mas como errada?

Comment: você está minificando os arquivos?

Comment: Como assim?
O angular.js estou usando o endereço web:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Minificado é o arquivo que (por convenção) possui a extensão `.min.js`, onde é feita a compressão do arquivo. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15019/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-uso-de-arquivos-js-e-min-js

Comment: Não, não estou usando o min.js

Comment: Você só possui um único state?

Comment: O `["ngRoute"]` na chamada do seu módulo não funciona apenas adicionando este plugin: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js ? Fez isso? Posso estar enganado, não sou muito experiente em Angular, mas imaginei isto.

Comment: Eu já tirei o ngRoute mas não adiantou.
Engraçado, pois tenho outra aplicação com angular e não tem esse problema.

Comment: Outra observação complementar ao @SamirBraga, não sei por que você está usando o `ui-router` e `ngRoute`juntos... É bem contraditório.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Você só possui um único state?

Comment: tente adicionar esse script 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Sim, só um state... Porém, acho que não seria necessário coloca state, pois só tenho o index.html

Comment: Me aconselharam usar 'ui-route', pois o ngRoute está sendo descontinuado. @DavidSchrammel.

Comment: Existe outra forma de passar parâmetros? Pois se eu tiro o $stateParams, o problema sai.

Comment: Consegui... Tirei a rota, o app.config e todo o resto, deixei só a primeira linha.
Vejam a modificação no post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando uma versão minificada do AngularJS, portanto os erros não estão sendo exibidos em formato extenso.

Em uma análise rápida, me parece que você está utilizando o injetor `$stateParams`, que pertence ao módulo [UI router da biblioteca Angular UI](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Entretanto, sua declaração de aplicação não a está incluindo.

Para solucionar o problema:

- Inclua uma menção ao módulo UI Router, utilizando por exemplo um CDN:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js

- Declare a dependência na inicialicação de sua aplicação:

  `var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);`

Comment: Qual seria a versão CDN do angular?
Agora tirei o $stateParams e parou de dar erro... Mas você quer dizer que para usá-lo tenho que importar o ui-route, é isso?

Comment: @GustavoSevero Existem vários CDNs para o Angular; para a versão 1.4.5 as URLs oficiais são `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js`, e versão não-minificada `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js`

Comment: @GustavoSevero Sim, caso você deseje utilizar o injetor `$stateParams` você precisará incluir menções ao módulo ui-route.