# Existe alguma outra razão para se comprimir JavaScript no código fonte além do de ficar com tamanho reduzido?

Tags: javascript, segurança, minificação

A maioria das bibliotecas vem com o código comprimido da seguinte forma

```
<script>(function(){function c(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src=b;document.getElementById("xjsd").appendChild(a)},0)}google.dljp=function(b,a){google.xjsu=b;c(a)};google.dlj=c;}).call(this);(function(){window.google.xjsrm=[];})();if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._DumpException=window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp('/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.ntp.en_US.FA_vN017Rto.O/m\x3dsx,jsa,ntp,d,csi/am\x3dBGg/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oH9nFbyjTsBefBncZNhBHui7Tkmvw','/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.ntp.en_US.FA_vN017Rto.O/m\x3dsx,jsa,ntp,d,csi/am\x3dBGg/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oH9nFbyjTsBefBncZNhBHui7Tkmvw');google.xjs=1;}
 ..........
```

Em uma linha enorme.

Quais as razões? O ganho na compressão é considerável? Esses códigos são feitos à mão por algum extraterrestre :)

Comment: possível duplicada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88058/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-minificar-scripts-js) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15019/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-uso-de-arquivos-js-e-min-js)

Comment: Reduzir o tamanho do arquivo JS é dos motivos.

Comment: beleza, acho que entendi o porque do nome min.js :) Tão óbvio e eu nunca pensei nisso!

Comment: Geralmente, os códigos não são escritos dessa forma. O código original passam por um processo para deixar o código "feio" *(uglify)* onde há a troca de nomes de variáveis e funções por nomes mais simples e menores, remoção dos espaços, tabulações e quebras de linha. Tudo isso com o intuito de diminuir o tamanho do código, torná-lo mais leve e difícil de entender e modificar de alguma forma, seja para melhoria ou por busca de falhas ou coisa do tipo.

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo muito boa essa explicação, era isso que queria saber ao perguntar se "são feitos a mão por algum extra-terrestre"

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, fico feliz de ter ajudado no entendimento ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pessoas acham que assim ninguém irá entender o código maravilhoso que ela escreveu, oque não deixa de ser verdade, dificulta um pouco. Em geral quem faz isso por esse objetivo geralmente não escrevem códigos tão bons assim. Mas costuma funcionar porque só vai tentar copiar quem é muito ruim para entender um código ofuscado. Quem é bom não perde tempo.

Alguns até acham que assim o software dela ficará mais seguro. Se for isso, é um grande erro. Segurança não pode se valer neste tipo de artifício. Até um executável não dá segurança, imagine um código fonte, segurança de vir de técnicas corretas.

Fora isto é só reduzir o tempo de carga do *script*. Se bem feito dá um ganho grande.