# Operador "||" em variáveis JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Recentemente lendo o [código de um plugin](https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker/blob/master/lib/vanilla-masker.js), eu reparei na definição de variáveis e objetos usando o operador `||` do JavaScript. Exemplo:

```
function ola(nome){
    nome = nome || "estranho";
    return "Olá, " + nome;
}
```

Eu nunca tinha visto o operador `||` ser utilizado fora de um `if()`, então minha pergunta é, sob quais circunstâncias o operador "ou" trabalha quando definindo variáveis? Como eu sei o que retornaria após o "ou"?

> <sup>Obs.: A maioria das respostas abaixo estão certas e trazem detalhes que se completam. Como apenas uma pode ser escolhida como "correta" eu escolhi a que trouxe, além da explicação, uma lista com o que é considerado falso ou verdadeiro pelo operador `||`, mas eu **recomendo fortemente** a leitura das demais respostas.</sup>

Comment: Inclusive, não só o `||` pode ser usado fora de um `if`, mas também o operador lógico `&&`: [O que significa o operador && em entre strings?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5864/o-que-significa-o-operador-em-entre-strings)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em uma [resposta semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5053/1925), expliquei o que significa essa operação. Dá-se o nome de **colescência**. Ai vai um trecho desta resposta que responde sua questão (sua questão, entretanto, não é uma duplicata):

O código abaixo:

```
var resultado = valorA || valorB;
```

é exatamente o mesmo que:

```
var resultado = valorA ? valorA : valorB;
```

Acontece que no javascript, praticamente todos os valores podem tratados de
forma lógica, ou seja, convertidos para verdadeiro ou falso. Quanto à operação
anterior, quando o valor `valorA` é tratado como verdadeiro, o resultado da
expressão é o seu próprio valor. Quando é tratado como falso, o resultado da
expressão é o valor `valorB`.

Devemos então entender o que é tratado como verdadeiro e como falso.

O que é falso:

- string vazia: ""
- número 0 (zero)
- false
- null
- undefined
- NaN

O que é verdadeiro:

- tudo que não for falso... incluindo os seguintes
- strings não vazias: "0", "true", **"false"** (é importante lembrar desse)
- todos os números diferentes de 0: 1, -1, -1000, 1/10
- true

**Alguns exemplos**

```
false || "texto qualquer"     // "texto qualquer"
"" || "texto qualquer"        // "texto qualquer"
0 || "texto qualquer"         // "texto qualquer"
null || "texto qualquer"      // "texto qualquer"
undefined || "texto qualquer" // "texto qualquer"

"algum texto" || "texto qualquer" // "algum texto"
1 || "texto qualquer"             // 1
```

Answer (score 20):

Isto é comum em funções (e não só) para casos em que a função é chamada sem serem passados argumentos. Ou seja se `nome` der falso (ie não estiver defenido), então ele toma o valor que estiver depois de `||`. Pode dizer-se que o segundo valor é um valor por defeito que é tomado caso o(s) anterior(es) não estejam defenidos ou tiverem valor booleano *false*. Deste modo garante que o código não dá erro.

Então `nome = nome || "estranho";` é o mesmo que:

```
if (nome) nome = nome;
else nome = "estranho"
```

Um bom exemplo é como escutar o mousewheel event

Um outro exemplo: em versões antigas do IE não havia addEventListener, mas sim attachEvent.
Muitas vezes, faz-se:

```
var addEvent = document.addEventListener || document.attachEvent;
```

Dessa maneira a nossa nova variável, que é uma referência a uma função nativa, assume o `attachEvent` caso o `addEventListener` não exista nesse browser.

Comment: É quase um if ternário então? Como `variavel == null ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse()`?

Comment: @GustavoCinque: exatamente. `valorA || valorB` é exatamente o mesmo que `valorA ? valorA : valorB`.

Answer (score 5):

Isso é usado para atribuição de valores-padrões a variáveis. Tem 3 fatores contribuindo para isso:

1. As expressões em JavaScript sempre retornam um valor. Então `nome || "estranho"`, sendo uma expressão, retorna algo – que no seu exemplo será usado como o valor atribuído a uma variável.
2. Uma característica do operador lógico `||` na linguagem é que ele faz *short-circuiting*, ou seja, abandona a interpretação do que está à direita do operador se a parte da esquerda já for `true`.
3. Strings não vazias são consideradas *truthy*, ou seja, agem como `true` em operações lógicas/booleanas.

Veja as consequências de tudo isso nos dois blocos de código a seguir:

```
var x = "um nome" || "estranho"; 
// "estranho" é ignorado via short-circuiting pois "um nome" é truthy
// equivale a var x = "um nome"
```

```
var x = "" || "estranho"; 
// x = "estranho"
// "" é falsey, então || retorna o valor à direita
```

Answer (score 4):

Em Javascript, uma expressão do tipo `a || b` é interpretada da seguinte forma:

- Avalie `a`; se não for avaliado como um dos valores lógicos "falsos", retorne `a`;
- Caso contrário, retorne `b`.

Os valores que são considerados falsos para esse tipo de lógica são: nulo (`null`), indefinido (`undefined`), falso explícito (`false`), string vazia (`""`), zero e *Not a Number* (`NaN`).

Esse código na pergunta serve para garantir que a variável `nome` estará preenchida. Supondo que ela seja inicializada com o valor `null` - sem esse tratamento, você poderia retornar `Olá, null`. Experimente rodar o código sem a parte `|| "estranho"`. ;)

Note que expressões com o ou lógico podem ser encadeadas. Quando você tem algo do tipo:

```
a || b || c || d || e;
```

O interpretador, em geral, entenderá como:

```
a || (b || (c || (d || e)));
```

Isso fará com que seja retornado o primeiro elemento da série que não for avaliado como falso lógico. Mas caso sejam todos falsos lógicos, o último elemento será retornado.

Algo semelhante ocorre com o operador `&&`. A diferença é que o "e" lógico retorna o primeiro elemento que for logicamente falso, ou o último a direita caso sejam todos logicamente verdadeiros. É o inverso do "ou".

Answer (score 2):

Em javascript o operador `||` vai avaliar a expressão e retornar o primeiro valor que não seja avaliado como falso. Se não encontrar nenhum retorna o elemento mais à direita.

Valores que são considerados `false` no javascript: `"", false, 0, undefined, null, NaN`
Na expressão: `nome || "estranho"` a lógica é a seguinte: se `nome` for diferente dos valores listados acima, ele vai retornar `nome`. Caso contrário ele vai avaliar o próximo valor, neste caso, `"estranho"`.