# Como passar valor de input para função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Como passar `values` de outros `inputs` (**como parâmetro**) para uma função que somente será executada em um determinado `input`?

```
<input id="nome" type="text" value="LocalHost"/>
<input id="email" type="email" value="email@email.com.br"/>
<input id="tel" type="tel" onChange="funcao()" value="(62)90000-0000"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function funcao(nome, email, telefone) {
   // valor do type="text", type="email" e type="tel"
}
```

Observação:

Os inputs estão dentro de um `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $res){?>
    <input id="nome" type="text" value="<?php echo $res['nome']; ?>"/>
    <input id="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $res['email']; ?>"/>
    <input id="tel" type="tel" onChange="funcao()" value="<?php echo $res['telefone']; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("nome").value;`...

Comment: @MagicHat, preciso que esses valores sejam passados como parâmetro da função...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função intermediária para lidar com o evento e passar os valores para sua função.

Algo assim:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function onChangePhone(e) {
      var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;
      funcao(nome,email,tel);
    }

    function funcao(nome, email, telefone) {
       console.log("Nome: " + nome);
       console.log("E-mail: " + email);
       console.log("Telefone: " + telefone);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="nome" type="text" value="LocalHost"/>
  <input id="email" type="email" value="email@email.com.br"/>
  <input id="tel" type="tel" onchange="onChangePhone()" value="(62)90000-0000"/>
</body>
```

Mas isto respondendo especificamente sua pergunta de *como enviar os valores de três inputs como parâmetros da função `funcao`*. Não sei a lógica que você quer aplicar, mas provavelmente você pode usar uma função só. Algo assim:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function funcao(e) {

      var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var telefone = document.getElementById('tel').value;

       console.log("Nome: " + nome);
       console.log("E-mail: " + email);
       console.log("Telefone: " + telefone);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="nome" type="text" value="LocalHost"/>
  <input id="email" type="email" value="email@email.com.br"/>
  <input id="tel" type="tel" onchange="funcao()" value="(62)90000-0000"/>
</body>
```

Apenas uma correção: o evento javascript nativo é em minúsculo ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)). Então o correto seria `onchange` ao invés de `onChange`, em que pese alguns navegadores entenderem as duas versões.

**EDITADO (após a atualização da pergunta)**

Primeira coisa, você não pode ter mais de um ID igual na mesma página, ou seja, os ID's devem ser únicos. No seu loop, você está atribuindo os ID's `nome`, `email` e `telefone` a mais de um elemento.

Então, neste caso, uma solução possível é **substituir os ID's por uma classe** (para referenciá-los posteriormente), e agrupá-los (esta parte é importante) em um **elemento pai** com uma classe `dados`.

Outra coisa, seu código da pergunta está com problema (código php misturado com o html), mas pode ter sido na hora de copiar/colar.

Coloquei uns comentários no javascript para explicar o que está acontecendo em cada etapa. Estas formas de obter o `event` e o `target` são bem populares e infelizmente são necessárias para se ter uma máxima compatibilidade.

Existem bibliotecas como o [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) que facilitam estas operações, mas é uma decisão sua se você quer incluí-la ou não, e foge do escopo da pergunta.

Aqui está o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function mudouTelefone(event) {
            /* 
                como você está usando javascript puro (vanilla),
                você tem que fazer alguns truques para manipular o objeto evento.
                Dependendo do navegador, ou ele vem como parâmetro da função, ou
                encontra-se como propriedade do objeto window.

            */  
            event = event || window.event;


            /* 
                a mesma coisa aqui. O alvo (target) do evento (ou seja, o elemento que foi clicado)
                pode vir como propriedade .target ou como propriedade .srcElement, a depender do navegador
            */
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

            /* pegamos a referência do pai, para depois procurar os filhos dele */
            var divDados = target.parentNode;

            /* procuramos os elementos dentro do pai divDados com o método .querySelector */
            var nome = divDados.querySelector('.nome').value;
            var email = divDados.querySelector('.email').value;
            var tel = divDados.querySelector('.tel').value;


            funcao(nome,email,tel);
        }

        function funcao(nome, email, tel) {
           console.log("Nome: " + nome);
           console.log("E-mail: " + email);
           console.log("Telefone: " + tel);
           alert("Nome: " + nome + ", E-mail: " + email + ", Telefone: " + tel);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach($resultado as $res){ ?>
    <div class="dados">
        <input class="nome" type="text" value="<?php echo $res['nome']; ?>"/>
        <input class="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $res['email']; ?>"/>
        <input class="tel" type="tel" onchange="mudouTelefone(event)" value="<?php echo $res['tel']; ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php } ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Uma última dica: se você ficou confuso com o operador `||`, tem uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38040/49387) aqui no SOpt que explica bem seu funcionamento.

**EDITADO 2 (após o OP ter mostrado o código atual)**

Baseado no seu código postado no pastebin, percebi que não era a mesma estrutura mostrada no exemplo, e isto influenciou na resposta. A estratégia que eu sugeri era agrupar seus inputs em uma tag que seria o **elemento em comum** de todos. Aí era só chamar o `parentNode` que ele encontraria o elemento pai (que colocamos a class `dados`), e a partir dele você localizaria os filhos.

Mas, no seu código real, o elemento em comum aos seus inputs está duas camadas acima `<tr />`, ou seja, a linha da tabela. Para funcionar, você deve acrescentar um `.parentNode` ao `.parentNode` para ele subir duas camadas no DOM. Algo assim:

```
function ultimaNFe(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    /* pegamos a referência o elemento em comum, no caso, dois nodes acima (a linha da tabela) */
    var trNode = target.parentNode.parentNode;

    /* procuramos os elementos dentro do tr com o método .querySelector */
    var id_emp = trNode.querySelector('.id-emp').value;
    var ultima_nfe = trNode.querySelector('.ultima-nfe').value;
    funcao(id_emp,ultima_nfe);
}
```

Desta forma, pode remover o div `dados`. Ficaria assim: http://pastebin.com/3Tr4kQ00

Answer (score 1):

Não acredito que seja a melhor forma a se fazer mas aqui esta:

```
<head>
        <script>
            function funcao(nome, email, telefone) {
                alert("nome: " + nome +" email: "+ email +" telefone: "+ telefone);
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="nome" type="text" value="LocalHost"/>
        <input id="email" type="email" value="email@email.com.br"/>
        <input id="tel" type="tel" onChange="funcao(nome.value, email.value, tel.value)" value="(62)90000-0000"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aWSSV/19/

Abs

Comment: um verdade, nem precisa getelement... boa

Comment: Olá Renato, o meu `alert` está a retornar `undefined`. @RenatoSerra

Comment: Ou melhor dizendo: ao realizar `debug`: nome, email e telefone estão `undefined`

Comment: estranho aqui esta trazendo normal, testei agora no chrome, esta em que navegador?

Comment: Google Chrome. Pode publicar no JSFiddle?

Comment: Coloqueii la http://jsfiddle.net/aWSSV/19/

Comment: Renato, aceita o convite para o chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52185/como-passar-valor-de-input-para-funcao-javascript @RenatoSerra